# Ongoing notifications

Tags: android

I am trying to create a notification that will appear in the "ongoing" area of the notification bar (like WeatherBug).

Here is the code that I am using:

```
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(lastContext, 0, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR)
```

From what I understand, FLAG_NO_CLEAR, should also prevent the notification from being cleared by pressing the Clear button, this is also not working

Any tips SO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are using the flags in the wrong place.

You should be doing:

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
```

After you create your `Notification` object and before you call `NotificationManager#notify`